# Using StyleSelector with ItemContainerStyle

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `ListBox` whose `ItemsSource` is simply a list of strings. I have a style which changes the template of the `ListBoxItem`s.
Here it is:

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyleBase" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" >
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel">
                    <CheckBox Focusable="False"
                    IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent} }">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </CheckBox>
                </StackPanel>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                        <Setter TargetName="stackPanel" Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="stackPanel" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I apply this style to the `ListBox` using another style :

```
<Style x:Key="Style" TargetType="ListBox">
    <Setter Property="AlternationCount" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource MyStyleBase}"/>
</Style>
```

Now this works great, until I want the foreground of the text of each `ListBoxItem` to be changed based on the string value of it. 
I am using a `StyleSelector` for this:

```
class MyStyleSelector : StyleSelector
{
    public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if((string)item == "Avatar")
            return Application.Current.MainWindow.FindResource("MyStyleBlue") as Style;
        return Application.Current.MainWindow.FindResource("MyStyleBlack") as Style;
    }
}
```

Here are my `MyStyleBlue` and `MyStyleBlack`:

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyleBlack" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyStyleBase}" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="MyStyleBlue" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyStyleBase}" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"></Setter>
</Style>
```

It doesn't work when I have the string "Avatar" in the `ListBoxItem`. It just displays the usual `MyStyleBase`(With foreground unchanged). But The `StyleSelector` is supposed to change the style to `MyStyleBlue` if the `ListBoxItem` is "Avatar". `MyStyleBlue` is supposed to change the foreground to blue (But it doesn't). What am I doing wrong?

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522156/itemcontainerstyle-blocks-itemcontainerstyleselector) which says `StyleSelector`s won't work if `ItemContainerStyle` is set. But then how do I use `StyleSelector` with `ItemContainerStyle` set? Is there any other way to do what I am wanting to do?

Answer (score 1):

When you use an `ItemStyleSelector` the item styles are returned from that StyleSelector, so setting `ItemContainerStyle` at the same time has no effect.

However, that doesn't matter, because the styles that you return from `MyStyleSelector` are already based on `MyStyleBase`. There is no need at all to also set `ItemContainerStyle` to `MyStyleBase`.

Comment: Thanks, so I removed the setter for the `ItemContainerStyle` in the style for the `Listbox` and added a changed the contentPresenter to `<ContentPresenter TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>` and changed the `Foreground` setters to `<Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" ...` and it worked. :)